# How To update list using lambda expression

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have two lists. lst contains ViewState Data i.e All the records of the gridview & second lstRank contains the list of integer(i.e ID) for only those records which are marked as checked (i.e Gridview contains a columns for checkbox). Now i want to update the lst bool status depending upon integer ID of lstRank. How it can be achieved by lambda expression

```
 List<Tuple<int, string, bool>> lst = (List<Tuple<int, string,bool>>)ViewState["gvData"];
 List<int> lstRank = gvDetails.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where(s => ((CheckBox)s.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
                                                                       .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(((Label)s.FindControl("lblRankCD")).Text)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I'm guessing you want to change `lst`'s contents so that the boolean values are `true` if the `int` exists in `lstRank`, or `false` if not?

Obviously, tuples are immutable, so if you want to change one of the values, you would have to generate new tuple instances. It's not clear what you mean when you say you specifically want to do this with a lambda expression, but I assume you probably mean that you don't want a solution that involves an explicit loop. So how about this:

```
lst = lst.Select(oldValues =>
    Tuple.Create(oldValues.Item1,
                 oldValues.Item2,
                 lstRank.Contains(oldValues.Item3))).ToList();
```

If `lstRank` is large, you might want to optimize by first building a `HashSet` out of it, since you'll be doing a lot of `Contains` calls.